# HtmlAgilityPack C# Nested divs

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Say I have an html document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="p_123">
        MyText Here
        <div id="p_456">
            MyText Again
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to parse it with HtmlAgilityPack using a Replacement Regex that wraps the search text in a span tag for highlighting. So the resulting highlighted text should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="p_123">
        <span class="highlighted">MyText</span> Here
        <div id="p_456">
            <span class="highlighted">MyText</span> Again
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is, if I loop through the divs, I end up highlighting on div `p_456` twice because `p_123` also contains `p_456`. The actual result looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyTest</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="p_123">
        <span class="highlighted">MyText</span> Here
        <div id="p_456">
            <span class="highlighted"><span class="highlighted">MyText</span></span> Again
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm using code that looks like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(someDataStream);
foreach (HtmlNode n in doc.DocumentNode)
{
    string evaluator = m => "<span class=\"highlighted\">" + m.Value + "</span>";
    n.InnerText = Regex.Replace(n.InnerText, "MyText", evaluator);
}
```

Is there a way so that when I select the InnerText of `p_123` it only returns me the text "MyText Here"? Without the other div? Or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. I find using Regex is not ideal for parsing HTML

```
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);

        foreach(var n in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div"))
        {
            var oldChild = n.FirstChild;
            var newNode = document.CreateElement("span");
            newNode.InnerHtml = oldChild.InnerText;
            newNode.Attributes.Add("class", "highlighted");
            n.ReplaceChild(newNode, oldChild);
        }
```